# How can I get to echo the Season Months

Tags: php

The programm I am trying to get to work basically I enter season eg winter or spring and then it displayes the months in that season In upper case.I am currently getting error (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) php and Im am not sure where to go from here.Any help thanks

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
//THE ARRAYS
$seasons = array('winter','spring','summer','autumn');

//MAKE THE CHARACTERS LOWER CASE OR HIGER CASE
$season = (isset($_POST['season']) && $_POST['season'] != "") ?          strtolower($_POST['season']) : '';

//in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array
if($season && in_array($season, $seasons)){                         
$months = array();
//keyvalue table
$month_name = array(
1 => "January",
2 => "February",
3 => "March",
4 => "April",
5 => "May",
6 => "June",
7 => "July",
8 => "Auguest",
9 => "September",
10 => "October",
11 => "November",)

//keyvalue table connected with seasons 
'winter' => array(1,2,11,12),
'spring' => array(3,4),
'summer' => array(5,6,7),
'autumn' => array(8,9,10),

if  $season=> winter echo 1,2,11,12;

}
}else{
echo "Invalid season entered";
}
```

Comment: Close `$month_name` line with a semicolon after `"November")` and semicolon instead of comma at the end seasons arrays lines

Comment: There are too much errors in your script for a Q&A (`'winter' => array`, `$season=>winter` ...). I think you have to take a look at [php basics](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php) before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$month_names` declaration.

```
$month_name = array(
    1 => "January",
    2 => "February",
    3 => "March",
    4 => "April",
    5 => "May",
    6 => "June",
    7 => "July",
    8 => "Auguest",
    9 => "September",
    10 => "October",
    11 => "November",
);
```

You are missing the semicolon. The comma at the end is optional, some like to leave dangling commas because it is easier when duplicating lines to add elements to array.  Dangling semicolon is valid syntax, it just gets ignored.  The code is more readable with indented values and closing `);` on a new line.

You also have other syntax errors, so I would learn more of the basics of PHP, and consider an editor with syntax highlighting.